# use texstudio internal viewer independently

Tags: texstudio

How do I use texstudio internal viewer independently?

I was impressed by its fast rendering.

On the subject, which do you think is the fastest (in rendering) pdf viewer? I don't care about loading time or other features. But when I view a heavy document with hi-res images, I don't want lags when I go through pages.

Comment: On a windows system, SumatraPDF is very fast.

Comment: While I like sumatra, and use it occasionally, I find it the slowest in terms of rendering, with the most pronounced lags when navigating.